# How to avoid a list element in a list model from being added to ListView in qml

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListModel`:

```
ListModel {
    id: sourceModel
    ListElement { sourceType: "Christian's Galexy"; sourceName: "Bluetooth"; visible: true }
    ListElement { sourceType: "BBC Radio"; sourceName: "DAB"; visible: true }
    ListElement { sourceType: "Media Library"; sourceName: "";  visible: false }
    ListElement { sourceType: "Chris's Music"; sourceName: "USB"; visible: false }
}
```

I have a `ListView`:

```
ListView {
    id: source_list
    width: parent.width; height: parent.height
    spacing: 6
    model: sourceModel
    delegate: sourceDelegate
    focus: true
    interactive: true
    clip: true
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
}
```

I only want to inflate `ListElement` which has visible attribute as true. I don't want to inflate the other list elements in the `ListView`. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) which really filters item, not just hides them. For example:

***FilterModel.h***

```
class FilterModel : public  QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QByteArray filterRole READ filterRole WRITE setFilterRole NOTIFY filterRoleChanged)
public:
    FilterModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    QByteArray filterRole() const;
    void setFilterRole(const QByteArray roleName);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    QByteArray m_filterRole;
signals:
    void filterRoleChanged();
};
```

***FilterModel.cpp***

```
FilterModel::FilterModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{}

QByteArray FilterModel::filterRole() const
{
    return m_filterRole;
}

void FilterModel::setFilterRole(const QByteArray roleName)
{
    if(roleName != m_filterRole) {
        m_filterRole = roleName;
        emit filterRoleChanged();
    }
}

bool FilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);
    int role = sourceModel()->roleNames().key(m_filterRole,(int)Qt::DisplayRole);
    QVariant data = index.data(role);
    QVariant returnedValue;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(const_cast<FilterModel *>(this), "filter",
            Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
            Q_ARG(QVariant, data));

    return returnedValue.toBool();
}
```

To make the filter flexible it uses Javascript function from  `FilterModel` item to sort items.

And so usage is:

```
ListModel {
    id: listModel
    ListElement { name: "name1"; visible: true }
    ListElement { name: "name2"; visible: true }
    ListElement { name: "name3"; visible: false }
    ListElement { name: "name4"; visible: true }
}

FilterModel {
    id: proxyModel
    sourceModel: listModel
    filterRole: "visible"
    function filter(value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

ListView {
    model: proxyModel
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 2
    delegate: Rectangle {
        height: 30;
        width: parent.width
        border{ width: 1; color: "#999" }
        color: "#DEDEDE"
        Text {
            anchors { centerIn: parent; margins: 5 }
            text: name
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

All the magic takes place in `FilterModel.filter()`. It should just return `false` to skip an item.

Comment: You don't need to write a `model` `Q_PROPERTY`, there is already a `sourceModel` property in `QAbstractProxyModel`. You should loop on all the roles of the model and to retrieve the data for each of them and pass it to the js function, not just get the default role.  
Alternatively you could use my still experimental library here : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/tree/feature/filters-and-sorters

Comment: Thanks @GrecKo for your notes and useful link, I've updated my example.

Comment: Great solution! Maybe add also that you have to register this new QML-Type via `qmlRegisterType<FilterModel>("cpp.filtermodel", 1, 0, "FilterModel");` and include it in the qml file with `import cpp.filtermodel 1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost solved your problem by yourself. All you need is to add `visible: model.visible` inside of your view's `delegate` (here: inside of implementation of `sourceDelegate`). For example, you'll have something like this:

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    width: parent.width; height: 30
    visible: model.visible
    border.width: 2
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "\"" + sourceType + "\", " + sourceName
    }
}
```