# How do I define a function "filter" for a QSortFilterProxyModel in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qsortfilterproxymodel

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801357/how-to-avoid-a-list-element-in-a-list-model-from-being-added-to-listview-in-qml#) question about filtering and in the answers someone suggested to use QSortFilterProxyModel. I tried that and it works for me. Now I want to create a globally accessible filter model so I want to define it in c++. The filter in qml looks like this:

```
FilterModel {
    id: proxyModel
    sourceModel: listModel
    filterRole: "visible"
    function filter(value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

How do I recreate that in c++? There are functions like setSourceModel and setFilterModel, but how can I set the function filter()?

Comment: See this project: https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, looks good. Makes a lot of things easier. I just have one problem: when I use that filter, it seems like it overwrites all values of the whole model every time a value changes. When I am in the middle of editing some text (in view) and some other values change (from c++), it resets my changes. Is there a way to only update the value that has been changed? I can achieve that when just using QSortFilterProxyModel.